# Clojure: (:refer-clojure :exclude [read]) apparently not working

Tags: clojure

I am having an issue with `(:refer-clojure :exclude [read])`. My setup is as follow:

I have a file `foo.clj` which is:

```
(ns foo.core)

(load "foo_bar")
```

Then I have a file `bar.clj` which is:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [read]))

(defn read [])
```

In my application, I did split a namespace in multiple file. This is why I have a series of `(load)` statements in the `foo.clj` file which is the entry point.

The problem is that when I compile this file, I am still getting the famous error:

> WARNING: read already refers to: #'clojure.core/read in namespace: clj-osf.crud, being replaced by: #'clj-osf.crud/read

I don't think this would be much of a problem, but the issue is that when I use that library from another application, that other application won't compile and tell me what `foo.core/read` simply doesn't exist.

I also tried to change `foo.clj` for:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [read]))

(load "foo_bar")
```

But the same issue happens. Is this a bug in Clojure, or am I missing something?

I am using Clojure 1.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the ns'es you are using match your file names. I'm not sure if that's just sloppy examples or if that's actually the issue.

Usually when you split a namespace across files, the loaded files should start with `(in-ns 'foo.core)`, not `(ns foo.core)`. clojure.pprint is a good example in core (it loads a bunch of sub files).

A fuller example:

foo/core.clj:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [read]))

(defn read [] "hi")
(load "bar")
```

foo/bar.clj:

```
(in-ns 'foo.core)
(defn read2 [] (str (read) " there"))
```

If I then start a repl:

```
user=> (require 'foo.core)
nil
user=> (foo.core/read)
"hi"
user=> (foo.core/read2)
"hi there"
```

Comment: great thanks! It was not due to a sloppy example, but really the guy behind the examples. I didn't notice that specificity. Mind sometime play tricks since I did this in other projects... Anyway, that was the issue.